# xxxx Does not exist in this current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I keep getting the error

> " XXXX does not exist in this current context".

I know there are plenty of similar questions, but they don't help me as I'm not very good at C# & asp.net.
I've been struggling with this piece of code. Basically I need to have a calculate cost (Which is mean tot be done in the Beverage class, and it outputted on the About page. 
My code is very messy as I honestly have next to no idea what I'm doing.

**Beverage class:**

```
public class Beverage
    {
        string fruit;
        int kg;
        int cost;
        int cal;

        public string getOutputString()
        {
            return " Your selected Beverage is made of " + kg + " of " + fruit + ". " +
            "The cost is £ " + cost + " and has " + cal + ".";
        }

        public static int CalculatePrice()
        {
            int cost = (TextBox1.text + TextBox2.text);
            int cal = TextBox1.Text + TextBox3.Text;
        }

    }
```

**About code behind:**

```
public partial class About : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyFruit = Session["Fruitname"] as List<string>; //Create new, if null
            if (MyFruit == null)
             MyFruit = new List<string>();
            DropDownList1.DataSource = MyFruit;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                decimal total = calculatePrice(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text,
                                               TextBox1.Text.Trim());

                lbl1.Text = "You would like " + TextBox1.Text.Trim() +
                    DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "(s) for a total of $" +
                    total.ToString();
            }

        }
            public List<string> MyFruit { get; set; }

    }
```

The errors are always for `TextBox1`, `TextBox2`, `TextBox3` & `calculatePrice`.

Comment: You can't access instance fields in a static method. Either make the fields static or the remove the `static` modifier on the method.

Comment: I don't see the method signatures of `CalculatePrice` are matching in both the classes. There is no overload as well. I think you are supposed to call `Beverage.CalculatePrice()` in `Button1_Click` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to access `TextBox1.Text` outside `About` class. Only this class will have access to this properties, as it inherits `System.Web.UI.Page`. `TextBox1.Text` doesn't have its scope in `Beverage` class. If you want to use these values in that class, pass them as input parameters to the method.